# Use the Same variable for "if is Class" condition for two different derived Classes

Tags: c#

I have a base interface:

```
public interface IKlarfDefect
{
    int TEST { get; set; }
    int DEFECTID { get; set; }
}
```

Which fathers these two classes:

```
    public interface IKlarfDefect
{
    int TEST { get; set; }
    int DEFECTID { get; set; }

    public List<RMTKlarfImageListInfo> KlarfImageList { get; set; } = new List<RMTKlarfImageListInfo>();
}


public class CIMKlarfDefect : IKlarfDefect
{
    public int TEST { get; set; }
    public int DEFECTID { get; set; }

    public List<CIMKlarfImageListInfo> KlarfImageList { get; set; } = new List<CIMKlarfImageListInfo>();
    
}
```

I have a function that goes through a list of IKlarfDefect:

```
internal static string CreateDefectListString(IEnumerable<IKlarfDefect> klarfDefectList)
{
    StringBuilder defectListString = new StringBuilder();
    defectListString.AppendLine("");
    foreach (var klarfDefect in klarfDefectList)
    {    
        if ((klarfDefect is CIMKlarfDefect klarfDefectGeneric || klarfDefect is RMTKlarfDefect klarfDefectGeneric) ) 
        {
            if (klarfDefectGeneric.KlarfImageList.Count == 0)
            {
                defectListString.Append("N;");
                defectListString.AppendLine();
            }

        }
    }
    
}
```

But Visual studio gives me the error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0128  A local variable or function named 'klarfDefectGeneric' is already defined in this scope
```

Is there any way for me to use the same variable "klarfDefectGeneric" name for both types inside that if condition?

Comment: No, you can't reuse the variable in that kind of expression. But wait, you probably don't need to do that, especially if `klarfDefect` is declared as `IKlarfDefect` or `object`. So what's `klarfDefect`? Are you missing a `foreach` loop on `klarfDefectList` where `klarfDefect` is the range variable?

Comment: @madreflection IKlarfDefect doesn't have that KlarfImageList so I can't use. It;s because both derived classes have different versions of KlarfImageList

Comment: Then Nigel Bess has the answer: another interface.

Comment: But your question still needs to be updated to indicate how `klarfDefect` is declared.

Comment: @madreflection I assume through `foreach` on the list

Comment: @NigelBess: Yes, which is why I proposed that possibility... but the question shouldn't leave anyone to assume that. It's incomplete.

Comment: Yes, that's much better. Now someone can clearly see that it's an `IKlarfDefect` reference and does not have a `KlarfImageList` property.

Comment: @NigelBess question has been updated to show how I declare klarfDefect

Comment: Where is the `KlarfImageList` property declared?

Comment: @EdmundSchweppe edited my question to include it. It's part of the derived classes. But I was trying to minimize the code I presented so it's not verbose.

Comment: You minimized it too much. See the [mre] guidance. In fact, you could've removed the `TEST` and `DEFECTID` properties, as those made no difference to the question.

Comment: @madreflection yeah you're 100% right. Thank you all for the feedback. I'll strive to write a better question next time so you don't have to guess. Thank you!

Comment: When creating a [MCVE], look at every single line of code. Is that line necessary to reproduce the problem? If not, then remove it. If removing it makes the problem unreproducible, then you've clearly removed too much. It's really not that hard to create one, it just takes some work on your part to properly narrow it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Is there any way for me to use the same variable "klarfDefectGeneric" name for both types inside that if condition?*

**No there is no way to do that specifically.**

But you can get the same functionality by creating another interface:

```
public interface IHasKlarfImageList
{
    List<Image> KlarfImageList{ get; }
}
```

Then inherit the interface in your two special classes:

```
RMTKlarfDefect : IKlarfDefect, IHasKlarfImageList
```

And now you can do this:

```
if ((klarfDefect is IHasKlarfImageList klarfDefectGeneric ) 
{
    if (klarfDefectGeneric.KlarfImageList.Count == 0)
    {
        defectListString.Append("N;");
        defectListString.AppendLine();
    }
}
```

Please be aware that if you find yourself doing something like `if obj is type TypeA do X, else if obj is TypeB do Y` you are violating the Open-Closed principle and failing to make proper use of polymorphism. Those are big words but the concepts are not as intimidating as they sound. Please save yourself (and the people you work with) a huge headache by building an understanding of those concepts. Polymorphism is the *entire purpose* of writing an interface in the first place.

Comment: question has been updated to show how I declare klarfDefect

Comment: @Datboydozy My answer did not depend on that and still solves your problem

Comment: There is an issue. It is not passing that condition. Even though RMTKlarfDefect  inherits from both IKlarfDefect and IHasKlarfImageList<TImageListInfo>.

Comment: `if(klarfDefect is IHasKlarfImageList<TImageListInfo> klarfDefectGeneric)`

Comment: I did that. But the issue is, I think C# is literally asking itself if it's directly the class. I think it's failing because the if statement only works if klarfDefect is exactly IHasKlarfImageList<TImageListInfo>.

It isn't. It's just derived from it so it fails

Comment: @Datboydozy Nope you have a different issue. First of all you don't "inherit" interfaces, you implement them. Second of all nothing can be of type `IHasKlarfImageList<TImageListInfo>` directly if `IHasKlarfImageList<TImageListInfo>` is an interface. The closest you can do is implement. Try checking if a List<string> `is IEnumerable<string>`. You will find the condition passes

Comment: The only thing I can think of that might be the issue is that RMTKlarfDefect also implements IKlarfDefect which doesn't implement from IHasKlarfImageList<TImageListInfo>. 

When debugging, it shows me that my type for klarfdefect is indeed RMTKlarfDefect which we know implements from IHasKlarfImageList<TImageListInfo>. 

So where could the issue be?

Comment: @Datboydozy send code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245248/discussion-between-datboydozy-and-nigel).

Comment: I created a chat. I am new to stackoverflow so I am not sure how to send you the code