# "If is class" Condition Failing

Tags: c#

Hi I have 3 base interfaces:

```
public interface IKlarfDefect
{
    int TEST { get; set; }
    int DEFECTID { get; set; }

}

public interface IKlarfDefect <TImageListInfo> : IKlarfDefect
{

    List<TImageListInfo> KlarfImageList { get; set; }
}

public interface IHasKlarfImageList<TImageListInfo>
{
    List<TImageListInfo> KlarfImageList { get; }
}
```

These classes implement it:

```
public class CIMKlarfDefect : IKlarfDefect, IHasKlarfImageList<CIMKlarfImageListInfo>
{
    public int TEST { get; set; }
    public int DEFECTID { get; set; }

    public List<CIMKlarfImageListInfo> KlarfImageList { get; set; } = new List<CIMKlarfImageListInfo>();
    
}

public class RMTKlarfDefect : IKlarfDefect, IHasKlarfImageList<CIMKlarfImageListInfo>
{
    public int TEST { get; set; }
    public int DEFECTID { get; set; }
    
    public List<RMTKlarfImageListInfo> KlarfImageList { get; set; } = new List<RMTKlarfImageListInfo>();
}
```

Then I have this function in another class that tries to read through these classes:

```
internal static string CreateCIMDefectListString(IEnumerable<IKlarfDefect<IKlarfImageListInfo>> klarfDefectList)
{
    StringBuilder defectListString = new StringBuilder();
    defectListString.AppendLine("");
    foreach (var klarfDefect in klarfDefectList) { 
        defectListString.Append(klarfDefect.TEST).Append(" ");
        defectListString.Append(klarfDefect.DEFECTID).Append(" ");
        
        if (klarfDefect is IHasKlarfImageList<IKlarfImageListInfo> grcKlarfDefect) 
        {
            if (grcKlarfDefect.KlarfImageList.Count == 0)
            {
                defectListString.Append("N;");
                defectListString.AppendLine();
            }
            
        }
    }
    return defectListString.ToString();

}
```

It compiles but the if statement fails when I am passing in either RMTKlarfDefect or CIMKlarfDefect. Might anyone know why this is?

if klarfDefect is IHasKlarfImageList grcKlarfDefect
fails as in, it doesn't return true which would allow it to process the imagelist

Comment: You said the if statement fails - but you need to describe how it fails. Does it not compile? Do you get an error? Please share the error.

Comment: I have edited it to describe what I mean by fail. It compiles but it doesn't return true

Comment: Can you explain how this is different from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72469129/use-the-same-variable-for-if-is-class-condition-for-two-different-derived-clas)?

Comment: Uh, so you're admitting to using multiple accounts, and breaking the rules?

Comment: Also, why don't you choose an answer to your previous question and give credit where credit is due?

Comment: The answer doesn't work though? How can I use it? @Nigel

I would mark it solved if it's working.

Comment: `if (klarfDefect is IHasKlarfImageList<CIMKlarfImageListInfo> grcKlarfDefect) `. You use the wrong generic interface.

Comment: @PoulBak I can't use it because both classes use different List<types>. It would fail for the other class.

Comment: @devn00b1090 That is irrelevant to your question. Your question is asking why the if statement fails. We have explained that for you. If you have further questions you can open a new question

Comment: @Nigel I will close my first question. I'm having an issue with an if statement that should return true. It doesn't. That's a new question which this post is supposed to be about. This post is a new question asking about why the "if statement" fails when I use an interface.

That other question was to see why I can't use the same variable name for two different classes.

Am i missing something?

Comment: @devn00b1090 why not select an answer anyway to give recognition for my help ... and the fact that I did in fact answer your question. It doesn't cost you anything to click the checkmark

Comment: @Nigel just did. THank you! I'm still learning on this site.  I was under the impression if a solution doesn't work, don't mark it as answered. But in this case you answered the question by that defition. Thanks for taking time to walk me through this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statement says

```
if (klarfDefect is IHasKlarfImageList<IKlarfImageListInfo> grcKlarfDefect)
```

But your classes implement

```
IHasKlarfImageList<CIMKlarfImageListInfo>
```

So you need to update your `if` statement accordingly:

```
 if (klarfDefect is IHasKlarfImageList<CIMKlarfImageListInfo> grcKlarfDefect)
```

Comment: The two classes implement different lists. One implements: List<CIMKlarfImageListInfo>
The other implements List<RMTKlarfImageListInfo> KlarfImageList

Comment: @devn00b1090 that is a different problem entirely. Narrow down your question to one problem at a time

Comment: But how is that a different problem. It is the same problem. I addressed it with the code provided.

Comment: "It compiles but the if statement fails when I am passing in either RMTKlarfDefect or CIMKlarfDefect. Might anyone know why this is?"
Your question is why the if statement fails. I have answered that. Including extra code does not extend your question, it just adds irrelevant information

Comment: Now it seems that your question is: "How can I implement an interfaces with differing generic type parameters?" or maybe "How can different interface implementations use lists of differing types?" Do you see how that is a different problem?

Comment: In this situation I think I do. Thanks. You've also answered this question so I'll mark it down. Thanks for babystepping me through both